# How to get value from IMAP (hazelcast) given the list of keys?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Problem we are trying to solve:
Give a list of Keys, what is the best way to get the value from IMap given the number of entries is around 500K?

Also we need to filter the values based on fields.

Here is the example map we are trying to read from.

Given `IMap[String, Object]`
We are using protobuf to serialize the object
Object can be say

```
Message test{ Required mac_address eth_mac = 1, ….// size can be around 300 bytes }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IMap.getAll(keySet)` if you know the keys beforehand. It's much better than single gets since it'll be much less network trips in a bulk operation.

For filtering, you can use predicates on `IMap.values(predicate)`, `IMap.entryset(predicate)` or `IMap.keyset(predicate)` based on what you want to filter.

See more: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query